# Loading security context into reactive context for reactive-returning controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

I'm trying to get security context within my reactive controller. If I use 
    `@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")` from SecurityExpressionRoot.class I can check in debugger that Authentication object is defined.
But when I try to get Authentication object within my controller by using something like

```
 ReactiveSecurityContextHolder
.getContext()
.map(securityContext -> securityContext.getAuthentication())
```

I get null. I found similar question with status open [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4859)

I've implemented my JWTAuthorizationWebFilter according to [this](https://github.com/raphaelDL/spring-webflux-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/io/rapha/spring/reactive/security/auth/JWTAuthorizationWebFilter.java)

Could you please suggest the way to solve this issue, or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: I'm using org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize, and then have a security context.  On the ServeRequest I get, I can also use request.principal().flatMap(p -> ...) to use the principal directly.  And BTW: The "similar quest" refers to a Servlet context, which means, that it's not reactive. Are you using Spring MVC somewhere?  Then this could be the reason for your troubles.